# Mutliple DispatcherTimer instances running simultaneously in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to generate screen shots of currently open windows, but each window must have its own DispatcherTimer where the image is generated on the Tick event. Each window has its own interval. The problem is that I fetch the list of windows from a database so I do not know at runtime how many DispatcherTimers need to create. So I won't know how many Tick event handlers I need to write.

Can someone show me an example where this can be dynamic based on the number of windows? This is what I can come up with so far. My list of windows comes from a component:

```
 private List<DispatcherTimer> m_dispatcherTimers;

m_mimicGroupsToCapture = SystemConfigurationComponent.GetViewCaptureMimicGroups();
        foreach (var mimicGroup in m_mimicGroupsToCapture)
        {
            m_dispatcherTimers.Add(new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(mimicGroup.CaptureIntervalInSeconds))});
            // Assign event handler to this instance's Tick event.
        }

        // Start all timers.
        foreach (var dispatcherTimer in m_dispatcherTimers)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: I dont know your architecture, but could you do something like: Have each Window implement an Interface that starts it's own dispatcher when it is created(could inherit from a base class too), Then when that dispatcher Ticks, it could have a callback to a singleton static class that takes the screen shots from it? This should allow for extend-ability. and then your main maintenance is in the static class that handles the callbacks on Tick. This is my knee-jerk thought after reading your issue.

Comment: @GingerNinja I don't have control over the Window implementation.Your thinking is probably more elegant of a solution.

Comment: Are you able to post any code you have to take a single screen shot of a window? Like how you pull it from the DB, then take the screenshot

Comment: _"I won't know how many Tick event handlers I need to write"_ -- I don't understand that statement. Why would you write more than _one_ handler? Assuming all of these windows have the same "screen shot" functionality, why wouldn't you just reuse the same event handler for each window's timer? The handler can be passed the unique window reference, so that it knows which window is actually being processed. But the _code_ of the handler itself should work for all windows.

Comment: Set Priority of all timers to DispatcherPriority.Send